# Send Textviews throught Whatsapp

Tags: android, textview, send, whatsapp

I need to send all textview of a layout as string through whatsapp method, but if the textview is null must send a blank text.

this is my code:

```
public void sendButton(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {

        TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAmor3);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAmor2);

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");

        if (textview3 == null) {


        } else {

        }




        String both = textview2 + "-" + textview3;

        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", 
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, both );

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
}
```

What do i must to do ?

thanks

Comment: *#TextView.getText().toString().trim();*

Comment: you  can't send the views. Only the text.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`String both = textview2 + "-" + textview3;`

to

`String both = textview2.getText().toString() + "-" + textview3.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't share Textviews with any app. you can share text written on that Textviews. so get Text using `textview3.getText().toString()` and then pass that to what's app Intent.

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("text/plain");

try {
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", 
    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
    //in catch block will be called
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "textString here" );

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```